# how to get value from this Object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some obj like this...

```
 tdata: [
    {
      name: 'jims',
      id: '30616'
    },
    {
      name: 'joms',
      id: '38330'
    }
  ]
```

I want to know how to get any values from this obj

thanks for every answer :)

Comment: [How to JS objects, courtesy of w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Comment: [JavaScript object basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```js
var  tdata= [
  {
    name: 'jims',
    id: '30616'
  },
  {
    name: 'joms',
    id: '38330'
  }
]
  
console.log(tdata[0].name);
```

First, you have to access the object from the array then you can access the properties of that object.